# Select specific columns in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv

I am working on a webproject. It is using angularjs on clientside.
One of the requirement is to display some data in a grid and give options to export the data into csv file.

I am trying to use ngCsv module for this functionality. I display data in the grid from a collection. While displaying I have control on what columns I can display. But while exporting the data to CSV all that I can use is the collection. When I use the collection it is exporting all the columns from the collection in the exported csv files. But I want to export only specific columns. There may be a way to select only specific columns from the collection in angularjs but I could not find a way to do it.

This is the function that loads apps on the controller

```
function loadApps() 
{
    appService.getApps().then(function (result) {
    vm.assets = result.data.items;});
}
```

This function is used to export the apps

```
vm.exportApps = function () {
        return vm.apps.filter(function (a) {
            return a.selected;
        });
    }
```

This is is from html

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-csv="vm.exportApps" filename="SelectedAppsList.csv">Export Apps </button>
```

Can somebody suggest as to what I can do to just select specific columns to export ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use *csv-column-order* attribute in your html code.

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-csv="vm.exportApps" csv-column-order="vm.columns" filename="SelectedAppsList.csv">Export Apps </button>
```

and specify what columns do you need

```
vm.columns = function () {
    return ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'];
};
```

they are from your array of objects

```
vm.apps = [{column1:10, column2:12, column3:13}, {column1:14, column2:15, column3:16}]
```

Comment: Using csv-column-order to specify which columns are exported worked for me. I used it in combination with csv-header to define the names for the selected columns. Thanks! This should be in the documentation.