# export csv in angular with filtering columns

Tags: csv

I have worked on export csv file i have done but i need to pic particular columns and show in csv now  i  am getting all the columns.I need to get particular columns to display in csv file now i am getting all the columns please suggest  me any answer.Now I am getting the all columns in the csv file need to filter some of the columns

```
    code:
 var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
    var row = "";
    var column="";

    for (var index in objArray[0]) {
      //Now convert each value to string and comma-separated
      //String(index).replace(/,/g, '');
      row += index + ',';
    }
    row = row.slice(0, -1);
  column=
    //append Label row with line break
    str += row + '\r\n';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var line = '';
      for (var index in array[i]) {
        if (line != '') line += ','

        line += array[i][index];
      }
      str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
```

Comment: You cam use ng-csv attribute Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768600/select-specific-columns-in-angularjs

Comment: its not working i am using anular2